# If I look into one of those infinite-reflection mirror rooms, would each deeper reflection show a scene from slightly further into the past?

Tags: speed-of-light

Since it takes light time to travel, if I look into one of those infinite-reflection mirror rooms, would each deeper reflection show a scene from slightly further into the past?

Comment: If you and I are standing 1 meter apart facing each other, you are seeing me as I was approximately 3 nanoseconds ago.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ass you stated, you will see a succession of images of the past, equally spaced in time.